# How to access different database based on different user in Spring Data Mongodb environment?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

In my current implementation, MongoDB architecture looks like

```
DB : schoola
Collections : 
 1. students
 2. users
```

```
DB : schoolb
Collections : 
 1. students
 2. users
```

And in **each instance** of Spring Server properties file I do -

```
SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_DATABASE: <dbname>
SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI: <URI to <dbname>>
```

Clearly this isn't scalable and I am already tired of maintaining different server instances.
Instead what I am looking for I will have a ***User DB***

```
DB : user
Collections :
 1. users (with fields {userName, password, associatedWith: <DB NAME OF THE SCHOOL USER IS ASSOCIATED WITH>)
```

***So how do I do the following?***
When the user tries to login in I try validate with *user/users* and if success I fetch the *associatedWith* value.
Then I connect to that DB and provide services to that user, again I don't to connect to mongodb with every Rest call, probably I need to maintain a userContext in memory.

Comment: You would do that with JDBC, having 2 different data sources and using the correct instance each time. But why? Why not just use one?

Comment: you should configure two data source, and reach the right one depending on your need. This [article](https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7) could help you

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to provide your own flavour of a `MongoDatabaseFactory`, that on `getMongoDatabase()`, reads the *tenant* from a context source and returns the `MongoDatabase` to use.

[This sample](https://github.com/naveenb92/spring-data-mongodb-multitenant) is a bit dated but gives an impression of the overall direction here.